# ObjC design - Asking for user input from within asynchronous "model" code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I hope this isn't a stupid question, but I have a need to ask the user for input and that need comes in the context of code that is executing asynchronous with the UI.  I am communicating with a server behind the scenes while the user may be doing other things on the UI.  At some point during the communication, input is needed from the user (something like a password).

My question isn't so much about how to get the information, I can easily fetch it using an AlertView or some such on the main queue.  What seems out of place to me is putting UI code inside my model code.  I have a class that is responsible for network communication and instantiating a UI elements from within that context just seems like poor design.

I have considered using NSNotificationCenter to broadcast the need for user input, or using a delegate.  The problem is that, there is no specific ViewController that can act as the delegate because the user could be on any screen when the need for this information arises and I don't want to duplicate notification handling code in every ViewController.  That leaves the app delegate.

So, in the world of iOS development, would one typically just leave the UI code in the model, or put the code in the app delegate, or is there some other design alternative that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decouple the GUI code out of the model code by having the GUI supply a block to the model which gets invoked whenever the GUI action is to be performed. Therefore the GUI is separated out of the model and just gets invoked by the model at the appropriate time.

You could use delegation or NSNotificationCenter if you had a view controller controller i.e. a meta view controller which doesn't have a view associated with it but manages all the other view controllers (if needed) and can present the prompting GUI on top of what ever view there happens to be when needed.

Comment: Thank you.  I did consider the idea of supplying a block, but that leaves me back in the app delegate.  This doesn't seem like a particularly bad thing to me since the app delegate is kicking everything off.  I think this is probably my best option.

Answer (score 2):

A delegate does not always have to be an instance of an object. It could simply be a class! The protocol methods in the delegate will have to start with a "+" to allow the class to respond to them. I have indeed come across your situation because I like to keep model code (non ui related) clean. There may be other workarounds depending on your situation.

If however a number of objects have to listen for your events then notifications are the solution here. Instead if all you need is to present an input view then only one delegate is required (you are not going to have multiple viewControllers presenting the input view at the same time are you... no).

Here is an example of supplying a class as a delegate:

```
[[DatabaseUpdateModel alloc] initWithDelegate: (id)[DatabaseUpdateModelDelegate class]];
```

and in the implementation of DatabaseUpdateModelDelegate.m you will have for example:

```
+(void) databaseUpdateModel:(DatabaseUpdateModel*)dbModel didFinishDownloadWithDatabasePath:(NSURL*)path
{
    //present UI element to rename database (or whatever the input is for);
}

+(void) databaseUpdateModel:(DatabaseUpdateModel*)dbModel didFaceNetworkError:(NSError*)error
{
    //present UI element to notify the user of the error;
}
```

DatabaseUpdateModel is of course not the best of names; I just named it that way to put forward my point..

With this approach, the DatabaseUpdateModelDelegate class could also send out notifications if multiple objects need to listen for the events. That way you avoid having your model unnecessarily send notifications (whether anything is listening or not). The delegate does all the work :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I had not considered the prospect of using a class as a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should use the following criteria:

1. Is the code correct?
2. Is the code understandable?
3. Is the code easily updated?
4. Is the code easy to debug?
5. Is the code modular so you can move it to new projects easily?
6. (Not to be ignored) Is the code easy to implement?

In this case, using an NSNotification is a reasonable option, perhaps passing a delegate for the user interface code to use when the user has entered a username & password. Remember that even after the user enters a username/password, the view should remain on screen until the network code has validated it.

Alternatively, you can make the AppDelegate public with the methods that you want. This is what we do. For example:

```
@protocol PasswordViewProtocol
-(void) showPasswordDialog:(NetworkObject*)delegate;  // delegate gets called when user hits "Login" with username+password
-(void) hidePasswordDialog;     // used if a networking error occurs
-(void) passwordWasIncorrect;   // show a red message in the view indicating an error occurred
-(void) passwordWasCorrect;     // remove the view, perhaps save the username+password
@end

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder<UIApplicationDelegate, PasswordViewProtocol>
@end

@interface UIApplication(typedDelegate)
+ (AppDelegate*)typedDelegate;
@end
```

Then you can call code with:

```
[UIApplication.typedDelegate showPasswordDialog:myNetworkObject];
```

There are many other ways to do the same thing, but this works and fits the criteria.

Comment: While this works, I believe placing such code in the appDelegate is not the right thing to do. The app delegate should be left as is or close to it's default as much as possible. There are exceptions of course, but the moment you start adding methods in there then a different approach is probably ideal. If an instance needs to be global, make use of singletons, shared instances (or what have you); if a method / function needs to be global, make it a class method in an appropriately named Class..

Comment: @EricS, I appreciate the bullet list, those are all good things to keep in mind.  It's a helpful reminder to consider the underlying goals that are behind good design rather than focusing on the design principles themselves.  While I think the app delegate will be involved in my solution, I will try to use it only to setup the plumbing and put my UI code in another class.

Comment: I don't know why you think that the AppDelegate should remain pristine, @pnizzle. It's the perfect place to perform application-wide operations - operations that take place as viewControllers come and go. Some people prefer having the rootViewController perform those operations and that's ok too. Creating a separate class for that is sometimes ok, but coordinating the network operations, application state (foreground/background changes, rotation, other operations), data storage, and user interface can make the code more complicated with little benefit.